# How to find common objects between heap snapshop in Google Dev Tools?

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, heap-dump

I am working on a Memory leak issue in my Angular 1.4.7 application. I have recorded couple of heap snapshots and i can see that the Array is keep increasing between my snapshots. How to identify the objects which are common between snapshots?

The comparison view only shows the Added and Deleted objects between snapshots. I was looking for common objects between the snapshots so that i can look which are my array's are still not being collected. Any idea?

I am trying to use the Summary view on a specific snapshot and finding objects which are in other snapshots too.

Your inputs will be greatly appreciated.

RA

Snapshot1
Snapshot2
Snapshot3

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Take two snapshots
2. Open the second one.
3. In the filter on the toolbar (the one that says 'All objects') select 'Objects allocated before Snapshot 1'.

Now you should only see objects that were allocated before Snapshot 1, but still present in Snapshot 2.